# ImageMagick's convert fails only when invoked through python's subprocess.call

Tags: python, imagemagick, subprocess, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert the first page of a pdf file to a thumbnail JPEG file. I have the code similar to the following python code.

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile, NamedTemporaryFile
import os
from subprocess import call
…
def createThumbnail(reporttempfile, thumbnailtempfile):
    # build the command for executing for extracting thumbnail
    command = "convert -resize 241x344 -background white -gravity center -extent 241x344 -quality 75" 
    csplit = command.split(' ')
    csplit.append("pdf:"+reporttempfile.name + "[0]")
    csplit.append(thumbnailtempfile.name)
    print "csplit = ", csplit
    print "cmd = %s" % " ".join(csplit)
    # run the command convert to create thumbnail
    retval = call(csplit)
    print "retval = %d" % retval
    return retval
```

When I invoke the above function I get the following output:

```
csplit =  ['convert', '-resize', '241x344', '-background', 'white', '-gravity', 'center', '-extent', '241x344', '-quality', '75', 'pdf:/tmp/reportfile0001_zeEJ8B.pdf[0]', '/tmp/thumbnail0001_DTPHGb.jpg']

cmd = convert -resize 241x344 -background white -gravity center -extent 241x344 -quality 75 pdf:/tmp/reportfile0001_zeEJ8B.pdf[0] /tmp/thumbnail0001_DTPHGb.jpg
   **** Error: Cannot find a 'startxref' anywhere in the file.
   **** Warning:  An error occurred while reading an XREF table.
   **** The file has been damaged.  This may have been caused
   **** by a problem while converting or transfering the file.
   **** Ghostscript will attempt to recover the data.
   **** Error:  Trailer is not found.

Requested FirstPage is greater than the number of pages in the file: 0
   No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage).

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.

convert.im6: Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/reportfile0001_zeEJ8B.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/677.
convert.im6: no images defined `/tmp/thumbnail0001_DTPHGb.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
retval = 1
1
```

However, when I invoke the command directly by typing on the shell, convert succeeds without any issues and I can see that .jpg file is correctly converted. The command used is (what is also printed in the output above):

```
convert -resize 241x344 -background white -gravity center -extent 241x344 -quality 75 pdf:/tmp/reportfile0001_zeEJ8B.pdf[0] /tmp/thumbnail0001_DTPHGb.jpg
```

I have seen this behaviour on Mac (10.9.5) with ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2015-04-09 and also with Ubuntu 14 with ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16.

I am at my wit's end as to why this is happening. Can somebody please help?

Regards,

SN

Comment: Not sure what you expect the command to do as you ask it to resize something when you haven't even read anything in yet. Try resizing and maybe extenting *after* you read the `PDF` so you have something to actually resize. *-background* and *-quality* are both `Settings` so they persist until changed, but `-resize` and `-extent` are both `Operators` so they need something to operate on. Try running `man convert` and look for `Settings` and then `Operators`.

Comment: Do you actually have a space separating the input filename from the output filename - I cannot see one. Can you temporarily create a single page PDF and simplify the input filename from `pdf:something[0]` to `simple.pdf`in case you are falling foul of quoting and splitting?

Comment: I am trying to resize the first page of the pdf to a thumbnail. I don't know why you say there is nothing to operate on. Look at the pdf argument added by the python statement **csplit.append("pdf:"+reporttempfile.name + "[0]")**. And the issue is that this problem appears only when invoking convert via python subprocess. If I invoke the command directly on shell it works well - so there is no question of space not being there either. And when invoking from subprocess the space is not supposed to be there as the arguments are to be sent as a list which I am doing.

Comment: I have simplified the command to **convert <<various arguments >> simple.pdf simple.jpg** and tried to invoke via python subprocess.call and it still did not work. Of course, it works when directly invoked on shell.

Comment: So, did the simple PDF already exist before the Python program started, or was it a named temporary file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the temporary file before it is read by `convert`. You can open the temporary file with the `delete=False` option to avoid deleting it when it is closed using its `close()` method. To delete it manually after the processing has finished, use its `unlink()` method which happens to be the same as the `os.unlink` function (you have to pass the temporary file `name` attribute as its first argument).